# Is it possible to attach to a docker container that is actively running flask?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The question is self explanatory but just wanted to add some details. I am running an ubuntu container containing some python flask code:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD app/ /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python3-pip python-dev build-essential
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install flask
EXPOSE 50000
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

The docker compose file looks something like this:

```
version: "2"
services:
  app:
    container_name: flask-app
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

How do I attach to the container and run an interactive bash shell? Currently the attach command just hangs without returning.

Comment: What is the command you're using which hangs?

Comment: docker attach [docker-instance-id]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Docker attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/):

> Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container
> ...
> Note: The attach command will display the output of the ENTRYPOINT/CMD process. This can appear as if the attach command is hung when in fact the process may simply not be interacting with the terminal at that time.

[Docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/):

> The docker exec command runs a new command in a running container.

**TL;DR**: You want `docker exec -it [docker-instance-id] /bin/sh` to get to a terminal. `docker attach` will just show you `stdout` from your flask app from that point on (which might be nothing, which is why it appears to hang).

Comment: Thanks this was what I was missing.